# How do I select codecommit trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I am trying to send a Slack message by attaching a CodeCommit trigger to an AWS Lambda function and calling the Lambda function when the source code is committed.

However, CodeCommit does not exist in the trigger list for the Lambda function.

My account is the master account.

How do I select codecommit trigger?

[image]

Comment: Are you in the aws-cn partition? Chances are that feature does not exist there. Maybe try setting up the trigger from the codecommit console instead of the lambda console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda-cc.html

Comment: @Paolo The search bar can only check the same configuration as in the screenshot.

Comment: @luk2302 I've tried editing the repository trigger in CodeCommit, but when I test the trigger I only get a TestTriggerFailure error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause.

The region I have chosen is Osaka. I changed the region of Lambda to Tokyo or Seoul and CodeCommit trigger appeared.